# Using RTABmap_ros with external GPS?

Tags: slam, navigation, gps, ros-melodic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there support to use an external GPS with RTABmap_ros? I have seen previous answers saying this was not supported, but you could possibly use robot_localization to get around it (https://answers.ros.org/question/225694/interfacing-rtabmap-and-robot_localization/). However, according to (http://introlab.github.io/rtabmap/) version 0.14 of RTABmap Tango has GPS support. Has this feature been added to the ROS version yet?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329165/using-rtabmap_ros-with-external-gps?/) by [kp12](https://answers.ros.org/users/44195/kp12/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Yes it is now available on ROS. It is mainly used for more robust graph optimization and loop closure detection. See this post: https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki/Robust-Graph-Optimization#multi-session

The input gps topic to `rtabmap` node is called `/rtabmap/gps/fix`, which is a [sensor_msgs::NavSatFix](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/NavSatFix.html) type.

Note that rtabmap >=0.18.1 is required. Right now, only binaries in ROS melodic have the option (kinetic will be also updated soon), otherwise rtabmap should be built [from source](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros#build-from-source).

cheers,
Mathieu

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2019-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PapaG](https://answers.ros.org/users/40565/papag/) on 2019-08-20**:
Hi matlabbe, when are kinetic binaries expected to be updated?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-08-21**:
0.19.3 should be released in Kinetic: http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=rtabmap

**Comment by [carlostojal](https://answers.ros.org/users/121009/carlostojal/) on 2022-10-17**:
Hi. Checking noetic [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros) I can't find references to any GPS topic. Was it deprecated? Thanks in advance.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2022-10-23**:
see https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/issues/828#issuecomment-1288193535